# How do I become Grand Duke in the Battle Chateau in Pokémon Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I became Duke in the Battle Chateau, battled all trainers, including Gym Leaders and the Elite Four (I know for sure since I kept track of it, taking the list and crossing off every trainer after I defeated one until I had them all), became the Champion, tried leaving and re-entering and I still didn't become Grand Duke. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you got the answer yet but here it is anyways:

- **Baron/Baroness** : 0 Points/0 Battles (You get this when you first enter the Battle Chateau)
- **Viscount/Viscountess** : 5 Points/5
  Battles
- **Earl/Countess** : 30 points/30 Battles
- **Marquis/Marchioness** : 100 points/100 Battles
- **Duke/Duchess** : 300 Points/300 Battles
- **Grand Duke/Grand Duchess** : 1000 Points /1000 Battles

Now the list below shows how many points you get for defeating each type of trainer.
(Each type after Baron gets unlocked to fight after ranking up)

- **Baron/Baroness** : 1 Point
- **Viscount/Viscountess** : 2 Points
- **Earl/Countess** : 3 Points
- **Marquis/Marchioness** : 4 Points (Regular Trainers)/5 Points (Gym Leaders)
- **Duke/Duchess** : 5 Points (Regular Trainers)/6 Points (Elite Four)

The Reward Points for **Duke/Duchess** are guesses on my part although I am sure about the others.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can remotely think of is try beating the Elite Four. (again.) It may or may not work, however I find that when I'm having a issue like this I just beat the Elite 4 again, and it'll solve it 9/10 times. The 1/10, I'll ask here. :)